# Listar Disponibles

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, tengo un procedimiento para mostrar vehiculos disponibles por cierto periodo, pero no esta funcionando, este es el código que tengo en las capas **persistencia y logica.**

**Persistencia:**

```
//public static List<Vehiculo> disponible(DateTime Ini, DateTime Fin)
        //{
        //    List<Vehiculo> vehiculodis = new List<Vehiculo>();
        //    string letmatv = "", marca = "", modelo = "", anclaje = "", tipo = "";
        //    int nrosmatv = 0, año = 0, cantP = 0, costo = 0, carg = 0;
        //    DateTime inicio = Ini;
        //    DateTime final = Fin;
        //    DateTime i;
        //    DateTime f;
        //    Alquiler aA = null;
        //    Vehiculo v = null;
        //    Utilitario U = null;
        //    string x = null;
        //    SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(conexion.STR);
        //    SqlCommand oComando = new SqlCommand("VehiculosDisponiblesPeriodo", oconexion);
        //    oComando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //    SqlParameter oComando1 = new SqlParameter("@desde", inicio);
        //    SqlParameter oComando2 = new SqlParameter("@hasta", final);
        //    oComando.Parameters.Add(oComando1);
        //    oComando.Parameters.Add(oComando2);
        //    SqlDataReader oreader;
        //    try
        //    {
        //        oconexion.Open();
        //        oreader = oComando.ExecuteReader();

        //        if (oreader.Read())
        //        {

        //                letmatv = (string)oreader["LetrasMatV"];
        //                nrosmatv = (int)oreader["NrosMatV"];
        //                marca = (string)oreader["marcaV"];
        //                modelo = (string)oreader["modeloV"];
        //                año = (int)oreader["añoV"];
        //                cantP = (int)oreader["cantPV"];
        //                costo = (int)oreader["costoDV"];
        //                i = (DateTime)oreader["fechaIni"];
        //                f = (DateTime)oreader["fechaFin"];
        //                aA = new Alquiler(i, f, v);
        //            }



        //            vehiculodis.Add(aA);
        //            return vehiculodis;

        //    }

        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        throw ex;
        //    }
        //    finally
        //    {
        //        oconexion.Close();
        //    }
```

**Logica:**

```
 //public static List<Alquiler> dispo(DateTime ini, DateTime fin)
        //{
        //    List<Alquiler> oAux = persistenciaAlquiler.//disponible(ini, fin);
        //    return oAux;
        //}
```

**Webform:**

```
protected void btnDis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime ini;
        DateTime fin;
        ini = Convert.ToDateTime(txtIni.Text);
        fin = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFin.Text);
        List<string> disponible = logicaAlquiler.dispo(ini, fin);
        for (int i = 0; i < disponible.Count; i++)
        {
            lstDis.Items.Add(disponible[i].ToString());


        }
```

Comment: Hola, cual es exactamente el error?

Comment: @Kingk No hace la lista al momento de ejecutarlo, no lista los discponibles, tira solo uno disponible, no todos

Comment: ¿Nadie va a mencionar que todo tu código está en comentarios? Hasta la respuesta... :)

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que para agregar los disponibles a la lista, utilizada un if, por ello solo se agrega a la lista el primer resultado de tu consulta sql. En lugar de ello utiliza un while, para agregar los disponibles. Seria así:

```
    //    try
    //    {
    //        oconexion.Open();
    //        oreader = oComando.ExecuteReader();

    //        while (oreader.Read())
    //        {

    //                letmatv = (string)oreader["LetrasMatV"];
    //                nrosmatv = (int)oreader["NrosMatV"];
    //                marca = (string)oreader["marcaV"];
    //                modelo = (string)oreader["modeloV"];
    //                año = (int)oreader["añoV"];
    //                cantP = (int)oreader["cantPV"];
    //                costo = (int)oreader["costoDV"];
    //                i = (DateTime)oreader["fechaIni"];
    //                f = (DateTime)oreader["fechaFin"];
    //                aA = new Alquiler(i, f, v);
                       vehiculodis.Add(aA);
    //            }

    //            return vehiculodis;

    //    }

    //    catch (Exception ex)
    //    {
    //        throw ex;
    //    }
    //    finally
    //    {
    //        oconexion.Close();
    //    }
```

Comment: voy a probarlo, estoy teniendo problemas con  aA = new Alquiler(i, f, v);
                       vehiculodis.Add(aA); me dice que tengo un problema con el contructor que no hay un constructor que tome 3 elementos